# Function is not called when defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am pretty sure I am defining the instance method as a function but am getting the error `TypeError: foundProduct.toggleOnSale is not a function` when calling the line marked with `<--` . I don't understand why this is happening.

```
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

productSchema.methods.toggleOnSale = function() {
    this.onSale = !this.onSale;
    return this.save();
}

const findProduct = async () => {
    const foundProduct = await Product.findOne({ name: 'Mountain Bike' });
    console.log(foundProduct)
    await foundProduct.toggleOnSale() <--
    console.log(foundProduct)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to try defining the methods on the schema before deriving the model class out of it:

```
const productSchema = /* ... */;

productSchema.methods.toggleOnSale = function() {
    this.onSale = !this.onSale;
    return this.save();
}

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)
```